# Pass row id in a table displayed using jstl to jquery on click of row

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

I am displaying list of data as table using jstl foreach loop.On click of a row,the respective ID value in the row needs to be sent to jquery onclick() function.
Table-

```
  <table border="1" width="90%" class="table-hover" id="warehouseValue">

    <tr>
        <th>Warehouse Id</th>
        <th>Warehouse Location</th>
        <th>Warehouse City</th>
        <th>Zone</th>
    </tr>

     <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.listWarehouse}" var="description">
         <tr>        
            <td>
               <input type="hidden" id="idValue" value="${description.getWarehouseId()}" />
               ${description.getWarehouseId()}
            </td>
            <td>${description.getWarehouseLocation()}</td>
            <td>${description.getWarehouseCity()}</td>
            <td>${description.getWarehouseDescription().getZone()}</td>
        </tr>
     </c:forEach> 
</table>
```

Jquery onclick() function-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#warehouseValue").click(function() {
      var rowId = document.getElementById("idValue").value;
      alert("new "+rowId);
   });
});
```

Here on click of any row only the first row's id-${description.getWarehouseId()} is getting displayed.
How do i make the respective Id value of each row be sent to onclick() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get like this. `td` has a child input element.

```
$("#warehouseValue").on('click','td',function(event) {
        // td has a child input 
        var value1 = $(event.target.children[0]).val();
        var value2 = $(event.target).children("input").val();
        console.log(value1+" "+value2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's too long for me to comment, but don't count this as an answer.

```
<tr>
    <th>Warehouse Id</th>
    <th>Warehouse Location</th>
    <th>Warehouse City</th>
    <th>Zone</th>
</tr>

 <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.listWarehouse}" var="description">
     <tr>        
        <td>
           <input type="hidden" class="id-input" id="idValue" value="${description.getWarehouseId()}" />
           ${description.getWarehouseId()}
        </td>
        <td>${description.getWarehouseLocation()}</td>
        <td>${description.getWarehouseCity()}</td>
        <td>${description.getWarehouseDescription().getZone()}</td>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#warehouseValue").on('click','tr',(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var rowID = $this.find('.id-input');      
      alert("new " + rowId);
   });
});
```

Comment: Getting new [object Object] as the output and not the Id